# How to continuously move a line in html5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am new to HTML 5 and JavaScript. I plan to move a line automatically on my canvas until I hit the stop button. So far, I have found an example that shows how to move a line continuously. I tried to add stop button functionality to this example.

However, the line stopped moving automatically. Instead, it moves a little bit each time I press stop. In order to find the error, I checked my developer console. The console suggested that maximum call stack size has exceeded.

Additionally, I plan to have two buttons that can move the line up and down is it possible? If yes, should pass a different points array to draw function. For example, if somebody clicks left, should I pass a new array in which x coordinate is fixed but y is increasing?

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" id="stop">Stop</button>
    <button type="button" id="left">Left</button>
    <button type="button" id="right">Right</button>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>

    <script>
        window.requestAnimFrame = (function () {
            return window.requestAnimationFrame || 
                   window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
                   window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
                   window.oRequestAnimationFrame || 
                   window.msRequestAnimationFrame || 
                   function ( /* function */ callback, /* DOMElement */ element) {
                       window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
                   };
        })();

        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"), ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvas.width = 400;
        canvas.height = 200;

        var points = [],
            currentPoint = 1,
            nextTime = new Date().getTime() + 500,
            pace = 150;

        // make some points
        for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            points.push({
                x: i * (canvas.width / 50),
                y: 100
            });
        }

        function draw(runAnimation) {
            if (runAnimation.value) {
                if (new Date().getTime() > nextTime) {
                    nextTime = new Date().getTime() + pace;

                    currentPoint++;
                    if (currentPoint > points.length) {
                        currentPoint = 0;
                    }
                }
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
                ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                ctx.strokeStyle = '#2068A8';
                ctx.fillStyle = '#2068A8';
                for (var p = 1, plen = currentPoint; p < plen; p++) {
                    ctx.lineTo(points[p].x, points[p].y);
                }
                ctx.stroke();

                requestAnimFrame(draw(runAnimation));

            }
        }

        var stop = document.getElementById('stop');
        var left = document.getElementById('left');
        var right = document.getElementById('right');
        /*
         * define the runAnimation boolean as an obect
         * so that it can be modified by reference
         */
        var runAnimation = {
            value: false
        };

        stop.addEventListener('click', function () {
            runAnimation.value = !runAnimation.value;

            if (runAnimation.value) {
                requestAnimationFrame(draw(runAnimation));
            }
        });

        left.addEventListener('click', function () {

        });

        right.addEventListener('click', function () {

        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is where you call requestAnimationFrame..

You have

```
requestAnimFrame(draw(runAnimation));
```

The `draw(runAnimation)` is calling and running the function `draw`, which then gets down the the same line and does the same thing, the function never gets a chance to exit and eventually the call stack overflows.

To fix change the line to

```
requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

Now you are just passing the referance to the function draw.

As you want the `runAnimation` value to be passed, you can not do this with `requestAnimationFrame` as it already has an argument passed to the draw function. (the time)

For this case it is easier for you just to change the function declaration from

```
function draw(runAnimation) {  // runAnimation holds the time as that
                               // is what requestAnimationFrame will
                               // pass as the first argument
```

Change it to

```
function draw(time){ // you can ignore the time as you don't need it
```

The variable `runAnimation` can still be seen inside the function as you have defined it in the same scope.

And the last change is to the stop event

```
    stop.addEventListener('click', function () {
        runAnimation.value = !runAnimation.value;

        if (runAnimation.value) {
            requestAnimationFrame(draw(runAnimation)); // You are calling
                                                       // draw, but you 
                                                       // should just pass
                                                       // a reference.
        }
    });
```

To

```
    stop.addEventListener('click', function () {
        runAnimation.value = !runAnimation.value;

        if (runAnimation.value) {
            requestAnimationFrame(draw);  // only the function reference is
                                          // needed.
        }
    });
```